# Data is getting duplicated when fetched from Firebase in a ListView

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, duplicates

I am trying to fetch all children of the "Students" instance in Firebase Real-Time Database in a ListView using `addValueEventListner`. But when I add a new entry it starts duplicating the previous entries in ListView (But not in RealTime Database), like I have uploaded 8 entries successfully, when I try to add the 9th one it Duplicates the 1st entry in the ListView and 9th no. added entry doesn't show al all. when I add the 10th entry It duplicates the 2nd entry in the ListView and so. It is not showing the next entries after the 8th and duplicates the previous ones. But in the Firebase database, everything is working great.

Here is my code of retrieving data from the Firebase database.

```
studentModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        allStudentsAdapter = new AllStudentsAdapter(ViewAllStudentsActivity.this, studentModelArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(allStudentsAdapter);


        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                studentModelArrayList.clear();

                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        StudentModel studentModel = postSnapshot.getValue(StudentModel.class);
                        studentModelArrayList.add(studentModel);
                    }
                allStudentsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ViewAllStudentsActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }
```

I have applied all my knowledge and surfed all the relevant stuff at StackOverflow, I don't know what I am doing wrong. Plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
I have solved it myself. Actually it was a problem with my listview (listview doesn't work well with Firebase) so I changed my listview into RecyclerView and now it's working like a charm. When I was requesting more data from Firebase then my listview started misbehaving like it was duplicating the entries. Now it is so much easy to handle the data through Recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

just put this lines instead of notifyingdataset after the for loop in ondatabse change `

```
 allStudentsAdapter = new AllStudentsAdapter(ViewAllStudentsActivity.this, studentModelArrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(allStudentsAdapter);`
```

then you will understand why this is happening sir.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it is showing the same behavior. I think the valueEventListner is duplicating the entries and blocking the new entries to show in ListView but I am unable to figure it out that how can I change it.

Comment: you can use addlistenerForSingleValueEvent because it call only once